# Using video_player flutter (Build Failed with an exception)

Tags: flutter

I tried to use video_player plugin in flutter. But, i get this error on debug console:

Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Multiple build operations failed.
> Cannot parse result path string:

How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What codes to provide? this is from gradle build error